# pipe multipe files to a single stream

Tags: node.js, stream

so i have an array of filenames.

I need to go through each of those, read it as a stream, pipe one by one to a final stream.

Erroneously, the code would look something like this:

```
var files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'];
var finalStream = fs.createReadStream()//throws(i need a file path here)
(function pipeSingleFile(file){
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    stream.on('end', function(){
      if(files.length > 0){
        pipeSingleFile( files.shift() );
      }
    });
    stream.pipe(finalStream);
})( files.shift() )

finalStream.pipe(someOtherStream);
finalStream.on('end', function(){
  //all the contents were piped to outside
});
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: To start with, your finalStream should be a writeStream (so `fs.createWriteStream()` )

Comment: thanks, but fs.createWriteStream also requires a file name

Comment: Well, then give it one ;)

Comment: yeah, but the whole idea of working with streams is that i don't want to work with temp files

Comment: Where do you want it to go to then?

Comment: I want the finalStream to pipe to another stream

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test the recursive solution you proposed, but it may not work since you're modifying the original `files` array (calling `files.shift()`) two times on each iteration: when passing it to your function and also inside. Here's my suggestion:

```
var files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'];

var writableStream = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt');

function pipeNext (files, destination) {
    if (files.length === 0) {
        destination.end();

        console.log('Done!');
    } else {
        var file = files.shift();
        var origin = fs.createReadStream(file);

        origin.once('end', function () {
            pipeNext(files, destination);
        });
        origin.pipe(destination, { end: false });

        console.log('piping file ' + file);
    }
}

pipeNext(files, writableStream);
```

I used a `Writable` stream on a file just as an example, but you could use whatever you want. You can wrap this logic into another function and pass your `Writable` stream to it.