# why fs.createReadStream only pipe one time?

Tags: node.js

I want pipe `fs.createReadStream` twice, the code is here:

```
fs.createReadStream('pdf-sample1.pdf')
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdf-sample2.pdf'))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdf-sample3.pdf'))
```

But i meet an error:

```
Error: Cannot pipe. Not readable.
    at WriteStream.Writable.pipe (_stream_writable.js:162:22)
    at repl:1:86
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
```

who can tell me the reason?

Comment: May be this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14174228/2651076

Answer (score 6):

You can't pipe a readable stream to another readable stream. The flow is:

```
readable.pipe(writable);
```

A writable, is this case, could be:

- a [Writable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable);
- a [Duplex Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex);
- or a [Transform Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform).

So, if you're trying to read multiple files and pipe them to a writable stream, you have to pipe each one to the writable stream and and pass `end: false` when doing it, because by default, a readable stream ends the writable stream when there's no more data to be read. Here's an example:

```
var ws = fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf');

fs.createReadStream('pdf-sample1.pdf').pipe(ws, { end: false });
fs.createReadStream('pdf-sample2.pdf').pipe(ws, { end: false });
fs.createReadStream('pdf-sample3.pdf').pipe(ws);
```

Of course, this is not the best way to do it, you could implement a function to wrap this logic in a more generic way, maybe with a loop or a [recursive solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29702201/2241993).

An even simpler solution would be to use a module that already solved this problem, like [this one here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appender).

Comment: in the above example, do the multiple calls to the `pipe()` method respect the order they are called in?  and does each call 'wait' until the previous call has finished?