# Cannot pipe, not readable for node

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am having problems downloading a zip file from the internet. I found countless of examples, but all return the same issue:

I work in NodeJS 12 LTS and Electron 10.

```
core.js:4197 ERROR Error [ERR_STREAM_CANNOT_PIPE]: Cannot pipe, not readable
    at ClientRequest.pipe (_http_outgoing.js:887)
```

The examples I found are e.g. this one here:

```
    import { request } from 'https';
    import * as fs from "fs";

    request("https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.4/node-v12.18.4-win-x86.zip")
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/Users/foo/Desktop/bas.zip'))
      .on('close', function () {
        console.log('File written!');
      });
```

It couldn't be easier than that, but nonetheless, this fails. The order should be like this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913540/why-fs-createreadstream-only-pipe-one-time))

```
readable.pipe(writable);
```

This error message doesn't make any sense. What am I missing here?

Comment: Which request library are you using for `request(...)`?

Comment: `import { request } from 'https';`

Comment: I added it to my question as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), `https.request` returns an instance of `ClientRequest` - a writable stream which you can pipe to in order to send files with your request. Trying to pipe from this *writable* stream into a file is the source of your error - you need a readable stream of the response instead.

To get the readable stream of the *response*, you should add a callback and pipe it from the response.

```
request("https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.4/node-v12.18.4-win-x86.zip", res => {
  res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/Users/foo/Desktop/bas.zip'))
     .on('close', function () {
       console.log('File written!');
     });
});
```

The native `https` api is not very friendly. What you originally wrote would have worked with the now-deprecated [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module, and perhaps you got it from a code snippet using the very same. Nowadays, we should use an updated module like [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got). Here's an example:

```
import * as got from 'got';
import * as fs from "fs";

got.stream("https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.4/node-v12.18.4-win-x86.zip")
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/Users/foo/Desktop/bas.zip'))
  .on('close', function () {
    console.log('File written!');
  });
```

Comment: An absolutely underrated answer for a thumbs up and just an accept button. Thanks so much!! I just copied it and it works. Diving now into the details :-)

Comment: @Daniel Glad it helped! Not that it's important, but I saw the accept checkmark for a few seconds and it vanished when I ninja-edited to add some details. Not sure what happened there!

Comment: Oh, true, fixed! :-)